# Ssup and Sdown series

Tags: python-3.x, series

Consider the following series:

Ssup=  1 to n series of (1/n)

Sdown=  n to 1 series of (1/n)

a)Write a program to calculate Ssup and Sdown as a function of n.
b)Make a log-log plot of (sup (n) -sdo (n)) / (abs (sup (n)) + abs (sdo (n)))
as a function of n.

The sup and sdo functions give equal results but for n = 6 there is already numerical difference in their results, and the goal is to represent these differences graphically. I don't know how to solve it, because running the code causes division by zero. How can I solve this?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=int(input("escolha um n: "))

def sup(n):
    r=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        r=r+(1/i)
    return r

def sdo(n):
    s=0
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        s=s+(1/i)
    return s 

def inteiro(n):
    x=[]
    for i in range(n+1):
        x=x+[i];
    return(x)

x=inteiro(n) 

def func(x):
    y=[]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y=y+[(sup(i)-sdo(i))/(abs(sup(i))+abs(sdo(i)))]
    return(y)

y=func(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.yscale('log')  
plt.xscale('log') 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your `func(x)` is the problem here. The for loop starts from 0, thereby leading to a divide by zero error. Use `range(1,len(x))` in the for loop inside the `func(x)`

Answer (score -1):

Ran through the edits
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1001,) and (1000,)